# Sonar launch error

Tags: sonarqube, sonar-runner

I am facing the below error when i try to start the sonar by using a mysql. Do i need to modify any details in the sonar.properties file with respect to the elastic configurations ?

Has anyone face a similar error before ?

```
014.12.15 21:38:49 WARN  sea[o.e.transport.netty]  [sonar-1418659692862] exception caught on transport layer [[id: ,9001]], closing connection
java.io.StreamCorruptedException: invalid internal transport message format
at    org.     elasticsearch.transport.netty.SizeHeaderFrameDecoder.decode(SizeHeaderFrameDecoder.java:46) ~[elasticsearch-1.1.2.jar:na]
at    org.elasticsearch.common.netty.handler.codec.frame.FrameDecoder.callDecode(FrameDecoder.java:425) ~[elasticsearch-1.1.2.jar:na]
```

Answer (score 2):

In your `sonar.properties`, you have:

```
#--------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
# SEARCH INDEX

# Elasticsearch is used to facilitate fast and accurate information retrieval.
# It is executed in a dedicated Java process.

# JVM options. Note that enabling the HotSpot Server VM mode (-server) is recommended.
#sonar.search.javaOpts=-Xmx256m -Xms256m -Xss256k -Djava.net.preferIPv4Stack=true \
#  -XX:+UseParNewGC -XX:+UseConcMarkSweepGC -XX:CMSInitiatingOccupancyFraction=75 \
#  -XX:+UseCMSInitiatingOccupancyOnly -XX:+HeapDumpOnOutOfMemoryError \
#  -Djava.awt.headless=true

# Elasticsearch port. Default is 9001. Use 0 to get a free port.
# This port must be private and must not be exposed to the Internet.
#sonar.search.port=9001
```

Uncomment `sonar.search.port` and set it to 0.

Answer (score 0):

1. Check for port availability.
2. Try working with new MySQL DB instance.

Comment: thank you... i did check the port...tried changing it.. i will try a new instance to see if that helps.